# Express + Angular routing causing infinite loop + crash

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm working on a Node app using Express as well as Angular. I'm using Angular for routing and have my routes setup like so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/main'
    //controller: 'IndexController'
}).when('/discover', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/discover'
}).when('/user/home', {  //HERES THE PROBLEM CHILD!!!!!
    templateUrl: '/partials/user/home'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
}]).config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Now, **whenever I try and call `/user/home` -- The page goes into an infinite loop** and keeps reloading the controller. I can see in the node console that the page was called from `partials/user/home` which definitely contains a Jade file. I've checked other posts, most of them are solved with ass the `/` in the beginning of the partials path, that didn't help here. The page loads fine if I transfer `home.jade` into the `/partials` directory with no sub directory. Any ideas?

Update: It seems the infinite loop happens anytime I try to load a partial in any sub-directory of partials.

Per request:

Node -- App.js:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

And routes/index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Open Innovation Station' });
}

exports.partials = function(req, res) {
res.render('partials/' + req.params.name);
}
```

Comment: Could you add your Node config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routing rule that you have specified for partials will not match any requests to subdirectories within the partials folder e.g. /partials/folder/file. The routing path matcher treats `/` as a delimiter between variables. Therefore in order to support having sub folders within your partials directory you will have to add another rule to your app and define a function to handle rendering this template. This is shown below:

app.js

```
app.get('/partials/:directory/:file', routes.subpartials);
```

routes/index.js

```
exports.subpartials = function (req, res) {
  var file = req.params.file,
      directory = req.params.directory;
  res.render('partials/' + directory + '/' + file);
};
```

Comment: Thx for the response gordy. Im away from my machine for the night but will try in the AM.

Comment: It's best to use a catch all * in your partial route ('/partials/*'), then use req.params[0] to get the file that was requested. If the file directories are the same, you can just render the param.

Comment: Awesome solution. Just now getting into Angular routing, was recently using Express to handle everything. This sub-directory had me at a loss for a bit. I tried something like this earlier, `app.get('/partials/user/:file'` but I must've missed something. Thanks again!

Comment: To have a catch all partials work nicely with nested partials without any explicitly referencing nested directory, I will do this `app.get('/partials/*', routes.subpartials);` and render this way `res.render('partials/' + req.params);` in the subpartials function.

Answer (score 12):

Using `html5Mode(true)`, you will have to concern yourself with any relative paths -- which you are using for your partials.  The recursion in your case, I believe, could have been resolved by adding:

```
<base href="/"></base>
```

to your `<head>`.

Comment: sure did; thanks for this.. Silly mistake on my end for not having relative paths then wondering why things were including infinite.

Comment: I can't believe that html5Mode would alter a templateUrl that is specified with a slash in front of it.  Would have expected that to be an absolute path. especially since the docs say so.