# Angular/JS Express app in infinite routing loop in production mode, works fine in development mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I have a webapp built on `generator-angular-fullstack`. It works fine in development mode (`grunt serve`), but gets stuck in what seems like an infinite routing loop when in production mode (`grunt serve:dist`).

My server console outputs this:

```
Express server running on http://localhost:9000 in production mode
finished populating things
finished populating users
GET / 200 39ms - 1.41kb
GET /views/ui-editor/editor.html 200 15ms - 1.41kb
```

This is what my NodeJS routing code looks like:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    // Server API Routes
    app.get('/api/awesomeThings', api.awesomeThings);

    app.post('/api/users', users.create);
    app.put('/api/users', users.changePassword);
    app.get('/api/users/me', users.me);
    app.get('/api/users/:id', users.show);

    app.post('/api/session', session.login);
    app.del('/api/session', session.logout);

    // All other routes to use Angular routing in app/scripts/app.js
    // TODO: redo so won't list all subfolders like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553847/express-angular-routing-causing-infinite-loop-crash
    app.get('/partials/*', index.partials);
    app.get('/common/*', index.partials);
    app.get('/ui-editor/*', index.partials);
    app.get('/*', middleware.setUserCookie, index.index);

    app.get('/:session', function(req, res) {
        res.render('views/index.html', {
            title: 'My App'
        });
    });

};
```

...and my AngularJS routing code:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/signup',
        controller: 'SignupCtrl'
    })
    .when('/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/settings',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
        authenticate: true
    })
    .when('/:session', {
        templateUrl: 'views/ui-editor/editor.html',
        controller: 'weldEditorController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/my-project'
    });
```

**UPDATE:** Since I suspect that files are copied wrong into the /dist folder, here is the contents of /dist:

```
|-/.git (files inside)
|-/lib
|---config
|-----config.js
|-----dummydata.js
|-----env
|-------all.js
|-------development.js
|-------production.js
|-------test.js
|-----express.js
|-----passport.js
|---controllers
|-----api.js
|-----index.js
|-----session.js
|-----users.js
|---middleware.js
|---models
|-----thing.js
|-----user.js
|---routes.js
|---socket.js
|-/package.json
|-/Procfile
|-/public
|---bower_components (files inside)
|---images (files inside)
|---scripts
|-----c9afc898.vendor.js
|-----e4b45689.scripts.js
|---styles
|-----a5896f90.main.css
|-/server.js
|-/views
|---404.html
|---index.html
|---partials
|-----login.html
|-----main.html
|-----navbar.html
|-----settings.html
|-----signup.html
|---ui-editor
|-----editor.html
|-----weldPropertiesPanel.html
```

Comment: Is there any output in browser console?

Comment: @AndreyShustariov: Nothing until I kill the server - then it spits out a number of GET requests for the client-side JS files.

Comment: See file/directory tree appended.

Comment: What makes you think, that this is an infinite route loop problem? Does the ```editor.html``` view gets rendered?

Comment: @AndreyShustariov I guessed that since Chrome status bar is switching between saying "Waiting for server..." then "Waiting for cache...", and eventually hangs. No `editor.html` doesn't render.

Comment: If someone could explain how AngularJS routing and ExpressJS routing work together, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem most likely appears when some of the assets can't load.

Because instead of sending a 404 the express server in the current configuration just sends back `index`, as this line in `routes.js`, causing an infinite loop and crashing the browser window:

```
app.get('/*', middleware.setUserCookie, index.index);
```

It might be just a font or an angular template that is not found.
You best bet for debugging is to change the line above to

```
app.get('/', middleware.setUserCookie, index.index);
```

and see which http requests fail in network tab.
then make sure your `grunt build` job copies over all the required files/folders.

Comment: It was a long time ago now but I think this fixed it. Thanks!